# fputs only returns unknown command

Tags: php, curl, irc

I have a very small script inwhich I'm trying to get it to post a command in IRC.

```
<?php

    set_time_limit(0);
    $socket = fsockopen("irc.twitch.tv", 6667);
    fputs($socket,"USER greatbritishbgbot\n");
    fputs($socket,"PASS oauth:95uf89rv74gawp93ilfafeqnihpxb74\n");
    fputs($socket,"NICK greatbritishbgbot\n");
    fputs($socket,"JOIN #greatbritishbg\n");
    $ircChannel = "#greatbritishbg";

    while($data = fgets($socket, 128)) {
        $msg = "test";
        fwrite($socket, "PRIVMSG " . $ircChannel . " :" . $msg . "\n");
        echo nl2br($data);
        flush();
    }


?>
```

Every time I execute this, I receive the error: `greatbritishbgbot HELP:Unknown command`.
What is the correct way of using fputs to run an IRC command?

Edit: This question was requested to be closed and downvoted because I am apparently asking for debugging information. Which is incorrect. I have asked for an explanation into how one should use fputs in comparison to how I use it.

I ended up using WildPHP which only needed me to modify a config file.

I highly recommend it.

Comment: @hek2mgl that doesn't work. Similar to the previous fputs which allow me to login and join a server. Also, If you downvoted me. Please explain why.

Comment: I didn't downvoted. Could you logout? Otherwise I get `Login unsuccessful`

Comment: Oh, I see, (srry) it is protected by a password.

Comment: @hek2mgl It's already logging in to the IRC. It simply cannot execute the command

Comment: Yes, but I would like to reproduce it.. Tried on freenode, but the login procedure is different there. Never did that, need some time to investigate

Comment: @hek2mgl using Twitch.tv IRC so I can connect to live streams

Comment: http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1302780-twitch-irc